# Fill color is not applied to the SVG path

Tags: svg

To draw some shape based on the data, I am using the SVG path, but with a particular height and width, fill color is not applied to the path element properly. Just copied my path direction and created a sample below, if you change the width for SVG, the path is filled properly

```html
<svg height="450" width="450">
  <path d="M 0 118.65730685696555 L 0 0 L 46.4375 335.9090909090909 L 92.875 0 L 139.3125 0 L 185.75 0 L 278.625 0 L 325.0625 0 L 371.5 0 L 371.5 12.864603481624718 L 325.0625 13.465478183788035 L 278.625 28.056480133139154 L 185.75 64.31377161001998 L 139.3125 130.11162255466053 L 92.875 335.9090909090909 L 46.4375 335.9090909090909 L 0 118.65730685696555" />
</svg>
```

what will be the issue, how to fix this?

Comment: This is a bug in Chrome - works fine in Firefox and Safari. I'll file a bug. bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1197461

Answer (score 0):

If you tweak the path just slightly so that the two points at the bottom left aren't coincident, Chrome can properly fill it.

```html
<svg height="450" width="450">
  <path d="M 0 118.65730685696555 L 0 0 L 46.4375 335.9090909090909 L 92.875 0 L 139.3125 0 L 185.75 0 L 278.625 0 L 325.0625 0 L 371.5 0 L 371.5 12.864603481624718 L 325.0625 13.465478183788035 L 278.625 28.056480133139154 L 185.75 64.31377161001998 L 139.3125 130.11162255466053 L 92.875 335.87 L 46.4375 335.9090909090909 L 0 118.65730685696555" />
</svg>
```